# Render camera view like 3d view?

Tags: camera

Ive come across this problem here : When i set my camera at the position which looks , i render it and it looks stretched and not so good . What camera settings should i have on?

[image]

As you can see , on the left side , it is upright , and everything looks handy dandy .

But on the **RIGHT** side , the render is stretched and its just ... ugly !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, that's caused by the **Aspect Ratio** setting you've made.

[image]

It will change the anamorphic pixel aspect, and output the final render based on the actual X/Y resolution in **Render** setting.

Set `1.000` for both X and Y, which is the default value, and will solve the stretching.